# Want to build iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone

What is the best application or programming languages to build an iOS application platform for chat application for beginner like me. Please anyone can tell me about it.

Comment: For this no need to post a question. Just google it you will get to know. You can go with the Swift. its easy to learn.

Answer (score -1):

Apple put a lot of effort in its new `**Swift**' language.

On any Mac computer, you will find **XCode** on the app store.
iBook has a nice and clear electronic copy of the guide.

I've gotta admit I was a bit circumspect ("yet a new language ?") but it appears has they sell it, solid and sound.
(It's compiled and based on llvm. It is open as well, perhaps MIT license?)

I think they basically came up with C# for iPhone (it may even spawn from `mono'?)
But, again, the license model for the source make it sound more promising.

I found the iBook guide for very comprehensive when it came to the very basic of the language and the libraries.

XCode comes with quite a few templates showcasing each major application type. (You can also check the other languages for yourself: Objective-C and javascript)

So the two complement nicely.

If you are starting from scratch, I see no reason not to start on this train.

Since it's straight from Apple, and if coming up with Android isn't yet part of your plan, it will also be your path of least resistance when it comes to technical difficulties.